# How to convert text to svg path in Python

Tags: python, svg, fonts, font-face

I'm looking for a way to convert the text in a specific font face (.ttf or .otf) into an SVG path. So that I can continue working with the path in vector graphics as drawSvg (or a similar Library)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want it inside a python script only, but an alternative would be use [cnc-text-tool](https://msurguy.github.io/cnc-text-tool/) or even text tool of **Inkscape** and then save it as plain SVG.